# How do I pan and zoom to the bounds of a map defined by the markers

Tags: javascript, leaflet

When I have 1 marker, it should zoom into the map to the marker (high zoom level? zoom more in)

When I have more than 1 marker then it should detect the edges defined by all markers (top, right, down and left) and zoom into this

I have this code:

```
lMap.fitBounds(new L.LatLngBounds(this.bounds));
```

What is next?

```
var zoom = lMap.getBoundsZoom(new L.LatLngBounds(this.bounds));
lMap.setZoom(zoom);
```

Or some pan/zoom inside method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ppGpV/) should show how to use `map.fitBounds` to do what you want.  Basically, just pass in an array of LatLng objects.

Answer (score -1):

you can create a bounding object

```
var bounding = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
```

add your markers to it

```
bounding.extend(myMarker1LatLng);
bounding.extend(myMarker2LatLng);
...
```

and then use that bounding object to set the map view

```
map.fitBounds(bounding);
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#LatLngBounds

Comment: I am just using the leaflet api

Answer (score -1):

I am pretty sure its Work

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

             for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                 var data = markers[i]

                 if (data.lat != '' && data.lng != '') {
                     var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);

                     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                         position: myLatlng,
                         icon: iconBase,
                         map: map,
                         title: data.Name


                     });
                 }
                 bounds.extend(myLatlng);
```

and for map view

```
map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter(), map.fitBounds(bounds));
```